# Has Unicode included these Classical Chinese characters?

Tags: characters, traditional-characters, classical-chinese, character-identification

I've found these characters in an old dictionary about Classical Chinese / Sino-Vietnamese / Vietnamese. Although they can be analyzed pictorially (I don't know better words), I personally can't find their Unicode encodings. So, I wonder whether they or their variants have been coded. Moreover, are they really Classical Chinese characters, or were they just mistaken to be Classical Chinese by some Vietnamese?

[Imgur album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehdbD.jpg)

Here are the description:

1. Left: 巾, Right: 由
2. Left: 舟, Right: 者
3. Left: 米, Right: 欠
4. Left: 盎, Right: 瓦
5. Left: 口, Right: 召
6. Left: 扌, Right: 乖
7. Left: 舌, Right: 單
8. Left: 忄, Right: 省
9. Up: 推, Down: 火
10. Up: 其, Down: 巾
11. Left: 犭, Right: 長
12. Left: 歹, Right: 曹
13. Left: 魚, Right: 小
14. Left: 僉, Right: 鳥
15. Up: 髟, Down: 兆
16. Left: 牜, Right: 霍
17. Left: 走, Right: 斗
18. Left: 米, Right: 周
19. Up: 髟, Down: 忿
20. Left: 米, Right: 孛

Comment: I believe these are Chu Nom 字喃, which are Vietnam-coined phono-semantic characters (形聲字). All standard Chu Nom are included in Unicode CJK Ideographs Extension B, if not included earlier.

Comment: @XuanruiQi First of all, Chu Nom does include a lot of intact Classical Chinese characters. Secondly, out of 19/20 found characters, according to Unicode sources, two are Chu Nom (the first two), three are from Kang Xi Dictionary (KXD), Taiwan and Chu Nom (3, 5, 20), one is Chu Nom and Taiwanese (number 6), one is from Hanyu Da Zidian (HDZ) and Taiwan (number 11), one is from HDZ (number 14), one is from Japan and UTC sources (number 17), the others (10) are from KXD and Taiwan. To conclude, I think almost all of these 20 characters are rare Classical Chinese.

Comment: @XuanruiQi Number 17 is also from Taiwan.

Answer (score 10):

U+2208E
 U+26A73
 U+25E37
 U+24B79
 U+20C09
 U+22BBF
 U+269F4
 U+2272B
 U+24350
 U+220DB
 U+247D4
 U+23A52
 U+29D56
 U+2A1C7
 U+29B31
 U+24705
﨣 U+FA23
 U+25E9D
髟＋忿？(not found) ( U+29B64 U+29B6E  U+29B09)
 U+25E78

Most of them are in the block of "CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B".
﨣 is in the block of "CJK Compatibility Ideographs".

If you cannot see some Chinese characters above, I suggest installing the [Hanazono font, 花園明朝體](http://fonts.jp/hanazono/).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a reference to ⿱髟忿 or not:  http://vietcenter.temple.edu/nlv/tttgaideos.php 2771::≪[髟忿]:⨂≫ (phẫn: x x) but that's the only thing I can find also

Comment: Depending on the image, I think it's  U+29B64. Also, can you share your method?

Comment: Depending on the image, the description might be wrong. However, phonetically, the description is right (忿 is the phonetic part). So, perhaps there hasn't been this character in Unicode.

Comment: Also, 﨣 U+FA23 has a duplicate from Extension B:  U+27EAF.

Comment: 1. Type out the characters using 倉頡輸入法 (Cang-Jie IM).
2. Search them on the [異體字知識庫](http://chardb.iis.sinica.edu.tw/).

Answer (score 2):

@hinen already answered the question.

I wanted to tackle this (you know, teach a man to fish and all that jazz):

> I personally can't find their Unicode encodings.

Your best bet is:

[字海·两分](http://zisea.com/zslf.htm)

you get a little search box like this:

[image: hi]

let's take your first character for instance:

> Left: 巾, Right: 由

and then we search:

[image: to]

as easy as that and we get:

[image: okay]

then we can click on our character and see more details:

[image: yup]

and we get our nice little:

> unicode码：2208E

and

> 复制字符：

Repeat process.

---

p.s.: (Not all characters are broken down so easily - sometimes you'll need to use your noggin' to figure out the right components.)